# Including eval / bind values in OnClientClick code

Tags: asp.net, javascript, visual-studio

I have a need to open a popup detail window from a gridview (VS 2005 / 2008).  What I am trying to do is in the markup for my TemplateColumn have an asp:Button control, sort of like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnShowDetails" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"
   CommandName="Details" Text="Order Details" 
   onClientClick="window.open('PubsOrderDetails.aspx?OrderId=<%# Eval("order_id") %>',
   '','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes, width=350, height=550');"
```

Of course, what isn't working is the appending of the <%# Eval...%> section to set the query string variable.

Any suggestions?  Or is there a far better way of achieving the same result?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe the way to do it is

> ```
> onClientClick=<%# string.Format("window.open('PubsOrderDetails.aspx?OrderId={0}',scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes, width=350, height=550);", Eval("order_id")) %>
> ```

Comment: I like doing it in the markup to avoid cluttering the codebehind for such a small operation.  I also avoid the use of FindControl whenever I can because it's not very quick.

Comment: I always have trouble with this approach inside of asp controls. But, if it works, go for it.

Comment: A word of warning - question asks about Eval and Bind, but this approach will only work for Eval. Bind is handled differently internally, and won't allow such constructs

Answer (score 2):

I like @[AviewAnew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102343/including-eval-bind-values-in-onclientclick-code#102373)'s suggestion, though you can also just write that from the code-behind by wiring up and event to the grid views ItemDataBound event.  You'd then use the FindControl method on the event args you get to grab a reference to your button, and set the *onclick* attribute to your window.open statement.

Answer (score 2):

Do this in the code-behind. Just use an event handler for gridview_RowDataBound. (My example uses a gridview with the id of "gvBoxes".

```
Private Sub gvBoxes_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvBoxes.RowDataBound
    Select Case e.Row.RowType
        Case DataControlRowType.DataRow
            Dim btn As Button = e.Row.FindControl("btnShowDetails")
            btn.OnClientClick = "window.open('PubsOrderDetails.aspx?OrderId=" & DataItem.Eval("OrderId") & "','','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes, width=350, height=550');"
    End Select 
End Sub
```