# Evaluate expression inside js function argument

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using the OnClientClick event to call a javascript function, I want to pass an argument which is the result of an evaluated expression, something like this

```
OnClientClick='JsFunction(<%# Eval("csproperty") %>);'
```

When I try this the argument does not get evaluated ans when I tried to change apostrophe position I am getting parse erros. I am wondering if what I am trying to do is possible? Thanks for your help

Comment: The code you supplied shows the `Eval()` call being made in ASP.Net, not Javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Including eval / bind values in OnClientClick code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102343/including-eval-bind-values-in-onclientclick-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an invalid way to combine string and some code. Here is a valid version:

```
OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("JsFunction({0})", Eval("csproperty")) %>'
```

The idea is to put whole formatting of the attribute value inside `<%# %>`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but you just have to remove apostrophes, like this it worked OnClientClick=<%# String.Format("JsFunction({0})", Eval("csproperty")) %>);