# Passing a username into a url

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to set my user variable in my link equal to the current user's username.

Here is what I have:

```
<li><a runat="server" href="~/Profiles?user=<%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName() %>">Profile</a></li>
```

The url that I end up getting is this:

/Profiles?user=<%:%20Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()%20%>

How do I amend my code to properly place the username in the url?

I'm using the webforms template and identity 2.0

Comment: I don't know if there is a canonical duplicate for such questions, so meanwhile [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32477107/728795) should suffice

Comment: Constructing url with string concatenation should be used only when you've learnt URI RFC by heart. Otherwise - use existing methods - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517798/append-values-to-query-string. After properly constructing url use link suggested by @Andrei to write it as href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `HREF` attribute set at runtime though like

Design:

```
<li><a id="A1" runat="server">Profile</a></li>
```

In Code:

```
this.A1.HRef = "~/Profiles?user=" + Context.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: Perfect example how not to construct url, otherwise good suggestion.

Comment: @alexei why is this a bad way to construct a url?

Comment: @hildk what if user name contains non [a-z0-9] characters?  Consider reading RFC just to be aware - http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7320